# How does the false-conditional work in "I made sandwiches if you want some"?

Tags: idioms, conditionals, reversed-conditional

This use of "if" has a completely different meaning than its normal conditional meaning. Can someone explain to me how this construction works, and provide other examples of this sort of thing?

Answer (score 21):

It is **elliptical**: a main clause like *[have some]* or *[please take some]* has been left out.

> I made sandwiches; [have some] if you want some.

It is akin to requests like these:

> Please come with me; if you would be so kind [I would be much obliged].
>
> Ladies and gentlemen; if you will come with me [I will be most thankful].

Somewhat similar is this construction:

> She's different, [you will understand] if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not so sure that this construction is really best understood as ellipsis, at least not in quite as simple a manner as [Cerberus suggests](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/137590).

Rather, I would argue that the example sentence:

> "I made sandwiches, if you want some."   (1)

should be understood as an instance of a more general construction:

> "[*statement of fact*], if [*the listener cares about the fact*]"

where, functionally, the purpose of the second half is to avoid implying any presumptions that someone might otherwise read into the first half.  Basically, it's a shorter way of saying "I made some sandwiches, but you don't have to take any just to be polite, and you certainly shouldn't assume that I thought you looked really hungry or anything."

As such, I believe the origin of this construction would be better understood as a generalization of similar (but more conventionally grammatical) expressions like:

> "Here are some sandwiches, if you want some."   (2)

or even:

> "You may take a sandwich, if you want some."   (3)

The conditional in sentence (3) is perfectly fine according to ordinary English grammar: if the listener wants a sandwich, they may take one.  One *could* argue that it's still redundant, in the sense that the listener is presumably permitted to take a sandwich even if they *don't* really want one, but the conditional still serves a useful function in informing the listener that the preceding statement of permission doesn't (at least on the face of it) carry any implied obligation, and that they're free to ignore it if the conditional is false.  Indeed, (3) could still further be seen as a polite rephrasing of:

> "Take a sandwich, if you want some."   (4)

which some might find too brusque, even if the blunt imperative is softened by the conditional following it.

Thus, we may see (3) as a softer rephrasing of (4), sacrificing some grammatical precision for politeness, and (2) in turn as a yet more more polite form of (3), carefully avoiding any overt implication that the speaker might have any authority over the listener, such that they could grant or deny them permission.  It *could* be seen as ellipsis of:

> "Here are some sandwiches; [you may take some] if you want some."   (2*)

but I would argue that it could just as easily be interpreted as a direct analogue of (3), where the direct statement of permission is simply replaced by a statement of fact *implying* the permission.

In a sense, the conditional in all of (1), (2) and (3) may be understood as a meta-conditional, not qualifying the factual existence of sandwiches as such, but rather the assumption that the listener should care about what was just said.  That is to say, I think (1) might be better expanded to:

> "I made some sandwiches, [which might interest you] if you want some."   (1*)

somewhat analogously to, say:

> "The sandwiches are over there, [which might interest you] if that's what you're looking for."

or even:

> "I'll be in my office, [which you might want to know] if you need me."

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I understand where your answer and mine are different. I is true that my *a main clause like [have some] or [please take some]* glosses over the exact formula of the hypothetical/historical main clause, but it was in no way meant to exclude the main clauses that you suggest in 2*–4. Your 2* is exactly what I meant. As to generalisation, yes, it is fair to assume that as an intermediary step between the ellipsis and current idiom.

Comment: @Cerberus: Fair enough; I may have read more into your answer than you were actually saying.

Comment: Perhaps I should have added more details.

Comment: @Cerberus: Anyway, the point I was trying to make (which, admittedly, might be seen as a hair-splittingly fine one) is that there's a difference between the expanded sentences (2*) and (1*) above, since in (2*), as in the examples in your answer, the conditional is taken as qualifying an implied imperative or potential statement ("have some" / "I'd be thankful"), whereas in my (1*) it's answering the implied question "Why are you telling me this?" At least to me, the latter more closely matches the way I'd understand (1), and it seems to fit the broader "[fact], if [you care]" pattern better.

Comment: I'm hungry now.